# How to take middle content between two strings?

Tags: python, regex

I need to take a middle content between two string separators, the fact is that I have three printed separators in the whole string, I need to take the second separator and get its middle content towards the last separator.

This is the example:

```
'__SEPARATOR__'\r\nVMlinux2@ubuntu:~$ ifconfig && echo '__SEPARATOR__'\r\nens33: flags=4163<UP, 'BROADCAST', 'RUNNING', 'MULTICAST>  mtu 1500inet 10.10.10.11  netmask 255.255.240.0  broadcast 10.10.10.255 __SEPARATOR__
```

The correct output must be:

```
\r\nens33: flags=4163<UP, 'BROADCAST', 'RUNNING', 'MULTICAST>  mtu 1500inet 10.10.10.11  netmask 255.255.240.0  broadcast 10.10.10.255
```

I tried with this regex but doesn't work:

```
'__SEPARATOR__'.*?'__SEPARATOR__'((.|\r|\n|\r\n|\n\r)*)__SEPARATOR__
```

My function:

```
def get_cmd_output(output):
  regex = r"'__SEPARATOR__'.*?'__SEPARATOR__'((.|\r|\n|\r\n|\n\r)*)__SEPARATOR__"
  output = re.search(regex, output).group(1)
  return output
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Regards.

Comment: Please show your python code.

Comment: Why regex? That's like using a chainsaw to cut a popsicle stick. `split()` is probably what you want here

Answer (score 3):

Why not

```
yourString.split('__SEPARATOR__')[2].lstrip("'")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to compile your `REGEX` with `DOTALL` flag, because of `\n` in your text:

```
  regex = re.compile(r"'__SEPARATOR__'.*?'__SEPARATOR__'(.*?)__SEPARATOR__", re.DOTALL)
```

by default `.` don't match `\n`, and you can simplify the REGEX `(.*?)`, But I think you don't need as the the answer provided using `split` is easier.